# Java RMI - automating in an IDE

Tags: java, rmi

I've been able to get the java RMI running in linux / windows through some command prompt action (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html goes into the gory details) but wondering if there is a way to do from within the IDE (i use netbeans).

Perhaps through an ant script or something? how do you do it?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend rmi. I prefer the hessian library or spring's http invoker which goes over http. No need to open a port, because normally port 80 is already open. See a simple example here: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/hessian-web-service-protocol-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about starting a registry with `rmiregistry`, then you can start a registry inside your server process.

To do it, in `Server` replace

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

with

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
```

Comment: that is pretty cool! thanks for that, so just one more thing left:

the standard java instructions say i should pass this to the compiler

-classpath ~/NetBeansProjects/Example/build/classes -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:~/NetBeansProjects/Example/build/classes/

Is there a workaround for this too perchance?

Comment: It's not needed for the simple case when the .class files for the classes being transferred between client and server are available on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know you stated you use NetBeans, but I've found [this](http://www.genady.net/rmi/index.html) plugin for Eclipse very useful.